# $\int_{\partial \Omega}fg=0$ iff $f=0$ ae, on Lipschitz domain

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded Lipschitz domain. Then for all $f \in L^1(\partial \Omega)$:

$\int_{\partial \Omega} fg=0, \; \forall g \in C^{\infty}(\partial \Omega) \Leftrightarrow f=0$ a.e. with respect to the measure of $\partial \Omega$.

In my opinion, "$\Leftarrow$" is easily shown since we have two bounded functions on the negligible set $supp_{\partial \Omega}(f)$, which implies that $\left\lvert \int_{\partial \Omega} fg\right\rvert \leq C \cdot \left\lvert supp_{\partial \Omega}(f)\right\rvert = 0$.

I'm struggling to show the second part though. It would be nice to have some steps of "smallest things" I have to show, please.

Also, the fact that $\Omega$ is bounded makes its boundary compact, which is obviously nice since we're dealing with integrals on it. But in which way does this matter to have a Lipschitz domain?

Comment: Why should $f$ be bounded? Doesn't matter tough, the integral is zero because that is always the case for functions supported on a measure zero subset. For the second part, approximate the indicator of e.g. $A_n := \left\{n \geq f \geq \frac{1}{n} \right\}$ by $C^{\infty}$ functions and calculate $\int_{\partial \Omega}{f 1_{A_n}} \geq \frac{1}{n} \vert A_n \vert$ using the assumption.

Comment: I’ll try this, thanks! For $f$, since it is an $L^1$, hasn’t have to be bounded?

Comment: Mmh. Thinking about it, I guess it only implies that its set of infinite points is negligible, right?

Comment: $f$ being bounded and having no (or only a measure subset of) points x with $f(x) = \infty$ aren't the same thing though...

Comment: Obviously, that’s what I meant

Answer (score 2):

One purpose of the Lipschitz condition is to ensure that there is some reasonable surface measure on $\partial \Omega$. In fact, I don't see another.

I presume that $C^{\infty}(\partial \Omega)$ are the restrictions of the functions from $C^{\infty}(U)$, where $U$ is some open subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ containing $\partial \Omega$.

Since $\partial \Omega$ is compact, the mapping
$$T(g) = \int_{\partial \Omega} fg$$
is a continuous linear functional on $C(\partial \Omega)$. If we show that this mapping equals zero for all $g\in C(\partial \Omega)$, then by the uniqueness in the [Riesz representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem) we find that $f=0$ almost everywhere.

Let $g\in C(\partial \Omega)$. By Tietze's theorem, there exists a continuous extension of $g$ to the whole of $\mathbb{R}^d$, call it $\tilde{g}$. We may additionally assume that it is compactly supported. Then note that we may approximate $\tilde{g}$ by a smooth function in the supremum norm (by convolving with a compactly supported [mollifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier)), that is, for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a smooth compactly supported $f_\epsilon$ such that
$$\|f_\epsilon - g\|_{\infty} < \epsilon.$$
Since by assumption $T(f_\epsilon) = 0$, we get that
$$|T(g)| = |T(g-f_\epsilon)| \leq \|f_\epsilon - g\|_{\infty}\int |f| < \epsilon \int |f|,$$
so by letting $\epsilon\to 0$ we obtain $T(g) = 0$.

Comment: Nice alternative answer, thank you!